# Series and Consistency

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, logic, real-numbers

Sometime ago I asked myself this question:

> Why manipulating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$ as $1$ leads to no contradiction in the arithmetic of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

More generally, why "treating" convergent series as numbers leads to no contradiction? I've found no satisfactory explanation to this question, maybe this is a meaningless question so nobody ever asked this.

I tried to come up with an answer, here it is:

We usually think of a convergent series as being a number, for example, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$ equals $1$.
But we should think the other way around, if $S$ is the set of all convergent series, we should think of "$=$" as being a function from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$, that associates every convergent series to its limit. Of course, for every real number we can find a infinite series that converge to it, but there are many different series, so we need an equivalent relation on $S$, two series being equivalent if they have the same limit.

Is my answer ok?

Does my question even make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: Or $\mathbb C$, not all series are over the reals.  One can see that $\sum 2^{-n}$ converges by convergence tests, so we can manipulate it since it is "equal" to something.  One cannot so simply manipulate $\sum 2^n$ as it does not converge.  Usually, we define $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ as $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$, which is probably less problematic in this sense.

Comment: Because we define $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{n} : = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N a_n$. The series *is* a real number.

Comment: The definition of a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim_{N\to \infty }\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \tag 1$$If the limit on the right-hand side of $(1)$ exists and is finite, then the series is said to converge.

Comment: In some sense, your questions is no different than asking "why are we manipulating 2 as if it was a real number?". After all, "2" is defined to be exactly the number "1+1". Just the same if we define $\sum^\infty 2^{-n}$ to be a number $x$ such that $x = \lim_N \sum^N 2^{-n}$, then it just turns out that that $x$ is equal to $2$, which is $1+1$.

Comment: @xyzzyz Hm, well, there are some different rules when it comes to manipulating the sum of an infinite amount of terms, so in that sense, its different.

Comment: Not really: rules are exactly the same, as long as you don't manipulate anything _inside_ the $\sum$ scope.

Comment: @Dr.MV That's the definition of the *sum* of the series. The series itself is the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: @zhw. I'm not sure to what you are referring.  [In this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Definition), a series is defined as the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, which is essentially the same definition as in my comment.  The sequence of partial sums is ... a sequence that if convergent, converges to the series.  Are we discussing semantics??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the notation "$\sum$" means. For an infinite summation, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$$ is *defined to be* the unique real number $b$ such that the finite partial sums "approach $b$", or formally, such that$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists N\forall m>N\left(\left\vert b-\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\right\vert<\epsilon\right),$$ if such a $b$ exists (note that at *most* one such $b$ exists).

We can now *prove* that e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}=1$, using the basic axioms of the real numbers (and this is a good exercise). We can also *prove* that some summations don't correspond to any real number, e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 7$.

Note that we're *not* allowed to just assume that an expression like "$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}$" corresponds to a real number (that is, is defined); we have to *prove* it. But once we've proved that it does, we've shown that "$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}$" is *a name* of some real number. Note that numbers have many names - e.g. $1=\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}={7\over 7}=\sin{\pi\over 2}$. There's no problem with having multiple series converge to the same value, any more than there is with multiple fractions evaluating to the same number.

---

That said, the picture you've given of a function from [names] to [values] is a very important one, and will come up in many fields of mathematics (some keywords include *free* groups/rings/etc., groups/rings/etc. *generated by some relations*, and - in logic and universal algebra - *term models*). However, I'd argue that it's not really the right picture for this particular context.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's clear in my head.

Answer (score -1):

One cannot always manipulate series is such a manner, even [(conditionally) converging series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence).

> The [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) says "if an infinite series is conditionally convergent, then its terms can be arranged in a permutation so that the new series converges to any given value, or diverges."

A famous one is the [paradox shown on the Simpson's](http://www.simonsingh.net/Simpsons_Mathematics/1-12-13-14-0/).  I will leave it to the reader to make conclusions about the manipulation of series.

You may find [other examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Examples) here.

Comment: I think this is answering a question different from the one the OP is asking; I believe the OP is asking how we are allowed to evaluate infinite sums in the first place, not how we are allowed to manipulate the expressions inside them.